# Get dynamically created image URL in a block with paragraph and media bundle

Tags: theming, uri

I have seen a lot of related answers to this question but nothing specific to my issue - apologies in advance if it has already been answered.

In Drupal 8, I have a custom block type that references a Paragraph type.  The Paragraph has a field that references an image media bundle.  So it looks something like this:

Block-> ReferenceFieldForParagraph-> Paragraph-> ReferenceFieldForMediaBundle-> MediaBundle-> ImageUploadField

I need to apply various image styles to that image and then get the URL for each image.

- In the Paragraph's Display, I have set the field that references the media bundle to display Thumbnail: Original Image
- I have created a twig template for the paragraph bundle and I am able
  to generate my various images by doing the following:

The media bundle reference field is named field_slide_image:

```
{% block paragraph %}
  {% block content %}

    {# set the styles #}
    {% set image1 = content.field_slide_image.0|merge({'#image_style': 'style1'}) %}
    {% set image2 = content.field_slide_image.0|merge({'#image_style': 'style2'}) %}
    {% set image3 = content.field_slide_image.0|merge({'#image_style': 'style3'}) %}

    {# render images #}
    {{ image1 }}
    {{ image2 }}
    {{ image3 }}

  {% endblock %}
{% endblock paragraph %}
```

I cannot figure out how to get the URL.  I have tried to use file_url() but I don't see any reference to the uri when I use kint.  In other words, something like this doesn't work:

```
{% set image1 = content.field_slide_image.0|merge({'#image_style': 'style1'}) %}
{% set uri1 = file_url(image1.uri.value)  %}
{{ uri1 }}
```

I need the url's so that I can create a custom responsive image using the picture tag.  I need to generate this dynamically because I have another field (select box) that specifies the dimensions of the images (ie the image styles).  For example, option 1 is a 1x1 ratio, option 2 is a 3x4 ratio, etc.  I could easily print all images and set up media queries to hide/display them but I don't want to resort to that if I don't have to.

Here is what I see when I kint image1

[image: kint]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't try to hack the render array `content`. You might be more successful with the `paragraph` entity:

```
{% set uri = paragraph.field_slide_image.0.entity.field_image_upload.entity.uri.value %}

{% set url1 = uri|image_style('style1') %}
{% set url2 = uri|image_style('style2') %}
{% set url3 = uri|image_style('style3') %}
```

For the filter `image_style` install the module [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak).